# Massive View Controller - IOS - Solutions

Tags: mvc, ios, objective-c

I'm sure every new iOS developer has the following problem: The View Controllers get very fast crowded with code for various purposes, easily getting to 500 + lines of code.

This is how it looks like for two basic and common screens:

1) The Form Screen:
[image]

2) The Table View Controller Screen
[image]

So far I have read about two different solutions:

1. First Solution: https://bendyworks.com/single-responsibility-principle-ios/.
   This is based on Notifications, it completely separates the View Controller from the (Intentions) View Model and thus reduces code in the View Controller. 
   I think that it has the downside of breaking code, similar to Go-To structures. 
   It looks like this:
   [image]
2. The second solution keeps the same crowded View Controllers (button actions are executed inside VC and so on). but uses libraries like [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoidings), BlocksKit or other solutions most of them based on categories. With this second solution, code is drastically reduced but the view controller still has a lot of responsibility.

What do you think about these solutions? Which is better? Is there a better one?

Comment: I can't give a good answer because of time, but [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: My intention is to collect as many good answers as possible to finally overcome this problem that so many new developers have. Thanks for the link, if I find something new I will surely post it here.

Comment: Here's a great talk about fighting with fat view controllers by Andy Matuschak [https://realm.io/news/andy-matuschak-refactor-mega-controller/](https://realm.io/news/andy-matuschak-refactor-mega-controller/)

Answer (score 5):

We can use MVVM to resolve this issue.

The Model-View-ViewModel, or MVVM pattern as it’s commonly known, is a UI design pattern. VM takes all logic about preparing model data for UI from VC.

Example:
You have got model object with some fields, you want to format some of them, make calculation and combine them.

In MVC case all that logic located in ViewController.
In MVVM you move all of it from VC to VM.

VM will prepare all data for UI and VC just sets it like this.

(in VC class)

```
self.descriptionLabel = self.viewModel.textForDescriptionLabel;
```

Tutorials and topics:

- [Introduction to MVVM](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/mvvm.html)
- [MVVM Tutorial with ReactiveCocoa](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1)
- [iOS Design Patterns: MVC and MVVM](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-morrison/ios-design-patterns-mvc-and-mvvm)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I agree with Bart. If no one else will post a summary of all these methods, I will make one as soon as I understand and test them all.

Comment: @Ravul updated answer

Comment: I have up-voted your answer and thank you for this idea. I am just reading about Functional Reactive Programming and it seems a good idea. I think the answer to this question is an enumeration, with a few advantages, disadvantages and at least one conceptual diagram for the following 4 ways to approach the problem: 1) Reactive Cocoa 2) KVO 3) Delegate method and 4) Classical way of writing a View Controller. I will write it as soon as I test all of these methods if no one else does so before me. If in the meantime I find new ways, that is even better.

Answer (score 3):

I've had to untangle code in massive-sized View Controllers before and it really impeded my ability to navigate content at first. One important thing I realized is that size alone of the View Controller wasn't reason enough to break things apart. There is complexity in having 1 large file and also complexity in having a bunch of little files. Here are some valid reasons to refactor to break a View Controller into smaller parts:

### MVC

The View Controller shouldn't be doing much more than being the connecting glue between the View and the Model. If you a lot of network connection code, image manipulation code, etc, then consider breaking those out into helper classes.

### Multiple Controls with the View Controller as a data source

If you have a bunch of controls on screen that have your View Controller as data source, consider breaking those into separate data source objects and have them be the data source. Or you can also break them into separate View Controllers (like if you View Controller has a table view in addition to other controller, you can break that into its own Table View Controller class).

### Duplicate Code

If you have the exact same code in different View Controllers put that in 1 shared location. That will make your code reusable and help manage the complexity.

Here is some additional advice to minimize View Controller complexity:

**Storyboard instead of Programmatic**

Creating View elements is a lot of code and frame geometry code is a lot of work as well. If not already consider using auto layout constraints and putting as much of the View elements in the storyboard as possible.

**Unnecessary code/comments**

Also be sure to remove unnecessary code/comments. A lot of times a new View Controller file will come with methods you are not using. If you aren't using a method like `didReceiveMemoryWarning` then it is safe to take it out. Also, because the View Controller file is so big sometimes it is scary to remove old code or comments. Don't put that off! It only adds to the complexity.

**Notifications**

To answer your question about notifications: Notifications aren't a Golden Hammer to use with everything. I find notifications to be useful when multiple View Controllers need to update at the same time because of 1 particular action. Be careful with notifications though, overusing them can cause you a lot of pain trying to track them down.

Answer (score 1):

There's one special architecture they call VIPER (View, Interactor, Presenter, Entity and Routing). I'll try resume here what you need know:

**View**

- they are dummy views;
- contain objects like UIView, UIViewController, UILabel, etc;
- waits the content from the *Presenter*;
- handle user interaction and pass it to *Presenter* layer.

**Presenter**

- doesn't know UI objects;
- get inputs from *View* layer;
- handle the view logic (add method will present other screen);

**Routing**

- handle the navigation logic and transition animations;
- knows objects like UINavigationController, UIWindow, etc;

So, what I think you will clean in your code:

- data validations will move to *Presenter* layer;
- navigation will move to Wireframe objects (*Routing* layer);
- split your view controller observing [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle;
- Complex screens will have two or more Views and Presenters.

You should see the follow link about VIPER architecture
http://mutualmobile.github.io/blog/2013/12/04/viper-introduction/

Good lucky!

Comment: Does this architecture works for small applications? Looks like you have to create a lot of objects to introduce it to the project.

Comment: yeah, I agree that it's more object than traditional MVC but it's worth. You can see one simple example I created this year https://github.com/orafaelreis/cascavel 
Cascavel is like a base project to initialize VIPER projects.

Comment: Excellent !  The VIPER architecture seems designed exactly to avoid the issue of massive view controllers.